# SQLite: Adding a column for date within the database

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

In my current application there is an SQLite database which is running as expected. However I would like to add a column for date to the database.

How do I add this column to the DatabaseHelper class below?

DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MultapplyDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_SCORE = "score";



    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
                + COL_NAME + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + COL_SCORE + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);


    }

    /**
     * Method that upgrades the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE); 

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);


    }

    /**
     * All CRUD operations
     */
    // Adding new score details (Name, score, date)
    void addScore(Score score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //ContentValues- holds the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME, score.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(COL_SCORE, score.getScore()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row (i.e. the values that were entered from above
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

}
    /**
     * Method will return a single Name and score
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    // Getting single contact
    Score getScore(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] { COL_NAME,
                COL_SCORE}, COL_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(cursor.getString(0),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
        // return contact
        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Method will return a list of all the scores
     * @return
     */
    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Score> getAllScores() {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return scoreList;
    }

}
```

The code below is the code section where the data is written to the database.

I.e. a Score object is added with columns Name and Score. In here I would like to also add the date the data was created within the Date column that I am adding to the Database. How do I do so?

```
/**


    * CRUD Operations
                 * */
                // Inserting Contacts
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addScore(new Score(UserName.getUserName(), score));

                // Reading all contacts
                Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                List<Score> scores = db.getAllScores();

                for (Score s : scores) {
                    String log = "Name: " + s.getName() + " ,Score: " + s.getScore();
                    // Writing Contacts to log
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);
                }
```

UPDATE:

now getting the following error:

```
07-02 21:31:44.785: E/SQLiteLog(2757): (1) table scores has no column named date
07-02 21:31:44.785: E/SQLiteDatabase(2757): Error inserting score=4 date=1404336704680 name=RooosYoungKen
07-02 21:31:44.785: E/SQLiteDatabase(2757):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

When trying to implement date using the following:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MultapplyDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "date";



    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //NOTE: may need to alter the below to take out everything after INTEGER
        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
                + COL_NAME + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + COL_SCORE + " INTEGER" + COL_DATE + "LONG" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);


    }

    /**
     * Method that upgrades the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE); 

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);


    }

    /**
     * All CRUD operations
     */
    // Adding new score details (Name, score, date)
    void addScore(Score score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //ContentValues- holds the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME, score.getName()); 
        values.put(COL_SCORE, score.getScore()); 
        values.put(COL_DATE, score.getDate());


        // Inserting Row (i.e. the values that were entered from above
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

}
    /**
     * Method will return a single Name and score
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    // Getting single contact
    Score getScore(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] { COL_NAME,
                COL_SCORE, COL_DATE}, COL_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(cursor.getString(0),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),cursor.getLong(2));
        // return contact
        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Method will return a list of all the scores
     * @return
     */
    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Score> getAllScores() {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                score.setDate(cursor.getLong(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return scoreList;
    }
```

}

And other class:

/**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addScore(new Score(UserName.getUserName(), score, System.currentTimeMillis() )); //need to add date to here

```
    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Score> scores = db.getAllScores();

    for (Score s : scores) {
        String log = "Name: " + s.getName() + " ,Score: " + s.getScore() + "Date: " + s.getDate();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }
}
```

Comment: The design here seems silly...is it creating a new table for every score/name combination?  Short answer is to modify the create_table_score to include a date column while it builds the statement.  Long answer = why are you adding and dropping tables like this?

Comment: I am not sure how to include a date column, and also not sure how add data to it within the program?

Comment: You can store a TimeStamp in your database as a Long value.

Comment: OK thank you, how to you create it though within the code? Not where creating the database, where the data is being entered. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Unfortunately, SQLite does not have a DATE type, however I would suggest to convert the current time into a `long` with `long dbLong = System.currentTimeMillis()`, insert that value into your sqlite table as a REAL or LONG. When you want to retrieve it, you can use `Date timestamp = new Date(dbLong)`

Comment: Please see my update to the code. I tried to use the method that you said but I am getting another error.

Comment: I see you updated your create query, but if I'm not mistaken there should be a "," after INTEGER in your `onCreate(SQLite db)` method

Comment: Actually I got it working! Thanks a lot! Is timestamp bascially a readable version of the system.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: The `timestamp` is a java.util.Date object that can be formatted in different ways depending on what you want. The `LONG` value that you are storing is basically the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Thanks! is there any way of converting the milisecond value since 1970 into the date and time so that it can be stored in that form in the SQLite database?

Comment: Using a SimpleDateFormat, you can convert your date object to a formatted string and then store that into your table as a `TEXT` column.  However, you open yourself up to parsing issues and you reduce the precision on your time stamp.

Comment: Thanks, how exactly would i do that in terms of exact code? Sorry I am quite new to android

Comment: Take a look at this http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html